# Combine Table with DateObject

Tags: date-and-time

I am trying to implement `Table` with a `DateObject` with the goal to obtain a series of increasing dates:

```
Table[
 DateObject[Today],
 {DateRange[Today, DatePlus[Today, Quantity[5, "Days"]]]}
]
```

The problem is that I obtain the same `DateObject` instead of increasing days:

```
{DateObject[{2020, 12, 29}, "Day", "Gregorian", 1.], 
 DateObject[{2020, 12, 29}, "Day", "Gregorian", 1.], 
 DateObject[{2020, 12, 29}, "Day", "Gregorian", 1.], 
 DateObject[{2020, 12, 29}, "Day", "Gregorian", 1.], 
 DateObject[{2020, 12, 29}, "Day", "Gregorian", 1.], 
 DateObject[{2020, 12, 29}, "Day", "Gregorian", 1.]}
```

How can I obtain a series of increasing days with `Table`?

Comment: Try `DateRange[Today, DatePlus[Today, Quantity[5, "Days"]]]`, explicit `Table` is not needed.

Comment: thanks for your comment. Unfortunately i need `Table` because later in the code i need to imlement a function, which is dependent on a `DateObject` like this: `Table[p1[DateObject[{2020,12,n}]],{n,1,20}]` and i would like toimplement this automatically with a 'Today' Any idea how this can be done with `Table` ?

Comment: @Pinco It would be a lot better if you described the problem you are actually trying to solve, i.e. what you mentioned in comments, rather than your attempt at its solution. I think the latter will get you off-topic answers. Would `p1 /@ DateRange[Today, Today + Quantity[20, "Days"]]` do? Or `Table[p1[i], {i, Today, Today + Quantity[20, "Days"], Quantity[1, "Days"]}]`?

Comment: @MarcoB thanks for your reply. Your line works fine for the function `p1` which requires only one argument as `DateObject`, but what if you need to map to another function `p2` which needs a second argument (a number) ? i tried the following: `testdata1 = 
 p2 /@ {DateRange[Today, Today + Quantity[500, "Days"]], 
   70.}` ? i get the following error when trying on p2 which requires a second argument: `PredictorFunction::mlbftlgth2: Example DateObject[{2020,12,29},Day,Gregorian,1.] should have 2 features instead of 4.` do you know how to implement p2 with a second argument?

Comment: `p2[#, 70]& /@ DateRange[...]`. You might want to read up on function construction a bit (e.g. [Pure functions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionalOperations.html#17469), [`Function` (i.e. `&`)](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html), [`Slot` (i.e. `#`)](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slot.html), and [`Map` (`/@`)](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html)). See also [this FAQ on all those funny characters in MMA](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25616/27951).

Comment: @MarcoB thanks again for your further reply. I implemented your suggestion (`testdata1 = 
  p2[#, 70] & /@ DateRange[Today, Today + Quantity[500, "Days"]];`) but i still get an error, the following: `PredictorFunction::mlbddataev: The data being evaluated is not formatted correctly.` Any clue what is still wrong ?

Comment: @Pinco No unfortunately that seems an error from `PredictorFunction` and it's hard to say without knowing more about your actual code

Comment: @MarcoB i was finally able to get the code working, the problem at this line was simply a matter of parenthesis:: `testdata1 = 
  p2[{#, 70}] & /@ DateRange[Today, Today + Quantity[365, "Days"]];` now it works. Thanks again

Answer (score 6):

If you insist on `Table`:

```
Table[
  i,
 {i, Today, DatePlus[Today, Quantity[5, "Days"]], Quantity[1, "Days"]}
]
```

But as Rohit mentioned in their comment, you don't need `Table` at all. This is literally what [`DateRange`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateRange.html) is for:

```
DateRange[Today, DatePlus[Today, Quantity[5, "Days"]]]
```

Both produce the same result:

```
{DateObject[{2020, 12, 29}, "Day", "Gregorian", -6.], 
 DateObject[{2020, 12, 30}, "Day", "Gregorian", -6.], 
 DateObject[{2020, 12, 31}, "Day", "Gregorian", -6.], 
 DateObject[{2021,  1,  1}, "Day", "Gregorian", -6.], 
 DateObject[{2021,  1,  2}, "Day", "Gregorian", -6.], 
 DateObject[{2021,  1,  3}, "Day", "Gregorian", -6.]}
```

Comment: One can even do something like `Table[p[i], {i, DateRange[Today, DatePlus[Today, Quantity[5, "Days"]], Quantity[1, "Days"]]}]` as an alternative to mapping a function `p` over the list of dates.

Comment: @J.M. Yes definitely. Indeed I had something similar in a comment, once OP explained the requirement down the road. I was also pleased to see that `Today + Quantity[5, "Days"]` also works, i.e. one can apparently avoid `DatePlus`. I find the former more natural and readable.